# Set Session Cookie Timeout in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Either I've got the worlds most popular site or theres something wrong with google analytics; the setSessionCookie timeout parameter is supposed to allow you to set the session length to the same length as the server session (in milliseconds); so I've set this for 20 minutes to match the server session... and visitors have quadrupled (I'm not that lucky; its also registering 4 times identical purchases which is impossible as the orderid is unique).

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    //<![CDATA[
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_setSessionCookieTimeout','1200000']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    //]]>

</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should there be quotes around timeout value?